# I can't get a short user token from facebook api graph tool

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got before an **access page token** to publish posts on a Facebook page and suddenly stopped working returning that error

```json
{
   "error":{
      "message":"Any of the pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata,\n pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_show_list or\n pages_messaging permission(s) must be granted before impersonating a\n user's page.",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":190,
      "fbtrace_id":"xxx"
   }
}
```

I googled a lot and no results about the error above!

So I have decided to generate a new token going Frist to Facebook Graph API Tool in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to generate a short user token and **I didn't find any permissions for managing pages** ( posting ) like the image below!! ( My app in development mode )

[image]